# How to close a cline socket from another thread in a concurrent java socket app

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I'm doing a socket app and I want to make an Admin clients and regular clients. Admin clients should be able to close the connection of other clients. I did the following but I get concurrent modification exception and sometimes socket exceptions

```
private void closeClientConectionHandler(String nickname) throws IOException {
    Iterator<clientHandler> list= clientList.iterator();
    while (list.hasNext()) {
        clientHandler client= list.next();
        if (client.getNickname().equals(nickname)) {
            client.clientSocket.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because something in another thread is modifying the list.  Once you have the code for the line `Iterator<clientHandler> list= clientList.iterator();`, that iterator becomes invalid once the list is modified (an item added or removed) by another thread.

Potential solutions are:

1. Use `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.  This list is thread safe.
2. Create your client list by:

```
    List<clientHandler> clientList= Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
```

Then wrap the code that you are using to iterate through the list with:

```
synchronized(clientList) {
    Iterator<clientHandler> list= clientList.iterator();
    while (list.hasNext()) {
        ...
    }
}
```

This will prevent other threads from modifying the list while you are iterating through it.